# Wordpress Javascript setAttribute on input field

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I wanna set an Attribute (inputmode="numeric") on an input field with JavaScript in Wordpress. For now I have this:

```
(function($) {
  document.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”, ()=>{
    Let numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll(‘input[type=“number”]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < numberInputs.length; i++) { 
      Let element = numberInputs[i]
      element. setAttribute("inputmode", "numeric")
    }
    })( jQuery );
```

It doesn't work unfortunately. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple errors inside your code. Here's a commented and fixed version:

```js
(function($) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    /*let needs to be lowercase*/ let numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'); // You forgot a closing quote and parenthesis. Also, the quotation marks you're using aren't actual ones
    
    for (let i = 0; i < numberInputs.length; i++) { 
      let element = numberInputs[i];
      element.setAttribute("inputmode", "numeric");
    }
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and help. I am pretty sure your code is correct. But it doesn't work. Maybe I should clarify the problem more. I use a Wordpress plugin with an number type input field. These input field has these attributes:
 <input type="number" step="' 
The css class are .input-text .qty .tex. tI want to add the input mode "numeric" to bring up the numeric keyboard on an mobile device. When I add the input mode in the plugin file, it works. But I wanna avoid this, because of Updates etc.

Comment: @deion apparently it doesn't work because the event listener name is using wrong quotation marks. See my edit.